# Executing expression delegate yields null reference exception

Tags: lambda, expression, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to execute a method created dynamically at run-time by parsing an XML template. I get the following from the "DebugView" of the expression lambda immediately before it is compiled:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<Reporting.Core.Formatter+WriterDriver>(
    Reporting.Core.IReportWriter $writer,
    System.Object $data) {
    .Block(
        Reporting.Core.IReportWriter $writer,
        System.Object $data) {
        .Call System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Initialize Driver");
        .Call System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($writer);
        .Block(Reporting.Core.IBannerWriter $bannerWriter) {
            $bannerWriter = .Call $writer.WriteBanner();
            .Call System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($bannerWriter);
            .Call $bannerWriter.WithLeftEntry(
                "Key1",
                "Value1");
            .Call $bannerWriter.WithLeftEntry(
                "Key 2",
                "Value 2");
            .Call $bannerWriter.WithRightEntry(
                "Another Key",
                "Another Value");
            .Call $bannerWriter.EndBanner()
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this, ensuring `myReportWriter` and `myData` are not `null` prior:

```
Action<IReportWriter, Object> Formatter = methodExpression.Compile();
Formatter(myReportWriter, myData)
```

<strike>In my trace output, I am not even getting the "Initialize Driver" output before the null reference exception is thrown.</strike>

Looking closer at the debug output shows it was in fact, getting to "Initialize Driver" and adding another debug check for null on $writer just inside the first .Block shows that `(writer == null) == true`. Now, the question is: Why is $writer null when it has been passed in to the method call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $writer and $data declarations in the first .Block were overriding the same from the .Lambda.

Changing the Expression generation logic from:

```
List<Expression> operations = new List<Expression>();
// populate operations...

var methodBody = Expression.Block(new[] {writer, data}, operations);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<IReportWrite, Object>>(methodBody, writer, data);
while (lambda.CanReduce) lambda.Reduce();

return lambda.Compile()
```

to:

```
List<Expression> operations = new List<Expression>();
// populate operations...

var methodBody = Expression.Block(operations);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<IReportWrite, Object>>(methodBody, writer, data);
while (lambda.CanReduce) lambda.Reduce();

return lambda.Compile()
```

This yielded an working expression tree as follows:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<Reporting.Core.Formatter+WriterDriver>(
    Reporting.Core.IReportWriter $writer,
    System.Object $data) {
    .Block() {
        .Call System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Initialize Driver");
        .Block(Reporting.Core.IBannerWriter $bannerWriter) {
            $bannerWriter = .Call $writer.WriteBanner();
            .Call System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($bannerWriter);
            .Call $bannerWriter.WithLeftEntry(
                "Key1",
                "Value1");
            .Call $bannerWriter.WithLeftEntry(
                "Key 2",
                "Value 2");
            .Call $bannerWriter.WithRightEntry(
                "Another Key",
                "Another Value");
            .Call $bannerWriter.EndBanner()
        }
    }
}
```